# Input value in form input if button is clicked (in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Here I have form in HTML

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name ="tes[]" id="tes1">
  <input type ="submit" value="Periksa Hasil" name="test">
 </form>
```

Button in the form will use to pass the data in php. That's why I make another button to set the value of form input like this:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="tes_ya(tes1);">Yes</button>
<button type="button" onclick="tes_no(tes1);">No</button>
```

So, if user click Yes, the value of form input is 1, and if user click No, the value will be 0.

I already make a javascript like this:

```js
function tes_ya(id){
   document.getElementById(id).value= 1;
  }
function tes_no(id){
   document.getElementById(id).value= 0;
  }
```

But I don't know, when I try it, the value can not e set. Is there anyone can help me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your click handlers for the buttons have an issue:

```
tes_ya(tes1);
```

`tes1` is not defined, so when `document.getElementById(id)` is called with it, it's essentially calling `document.getElementById(undefined)` (either that or the original code will get an error and utterly fail).

What you actually want is to pass the *string* `'tes1'`:

```
tes_ya('tes1');
```

Comment: OMG, yes! I feel so stupid I forget the quote. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid **onclick**.

Change:

```
<button type="button" onclick="tes_ya(tes1);">Yes</button>
```

to:

```
<button type="button" id="yes-btn">Yes</button>
```

Create a function that will copy the value from the text of the button:

```
function copyValue() {
    document.getElementById("tes1").value = this.textContent === "Yes" ? '1' : '0';
}
```

Then in your JavaScript attach an event handler like so:

```
document.getElementById("yes-btn").addEventListener("click", copyValue);
```